# Update array value a given index (mongoose, mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my **database**, I have in my schema a field: `priority_data: [ String ]`
This is an **array** of **priority** data.

Here is an example what that field can contain : 
`"priority_data": ["Photo","Video","Music"]`

And I want to **update** for example only the **index 2**.

I try to proceed with the following **code**:

```
await Disk.findOne({_id: id})
   .then(doc => {
   doc.disk_info[1] = 'Office Document';
   doc.save()
   .then(() => {
   res.status(200).json({
  message: 'ok'
})  
})
})
```

But that throws me an **error**.

Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Your question statement talks about a field called priority_data that is nowhere to be found in your code snippet. Does your schema also have a field called "disk_info"?

Comment: Add your schema and you exception please.

Comment: sorry the array is priority_data

Comment: when im doing doc.priority_data[1] = 'Office Document'; and after doc.save(); The index 1 of the array is not changed in my database

Comment: and the error was my mistakes the data expect an object but he receive string.

Answer (score 1):

```
await Disk.update(
    {_id: id},
    {$set:{"priority_data.1":"Office Document"}}
)
```